# Mcrypt and base64 with PHP and c#

Tags: c#, php, encryption, base64, mcrypt

I have written the same methods in two platforms which I believe should result same thing but its not happening. I have encrypted the same text with same key which result different. Can someone figure it out why is it happening ?

String: *this is test*

Key: *1234567812345678*

PHP encrypted string: *ybUaKwQlRNwOjJhxLWtLYQ==*

C# encrypted string: *r2YjEFPyDDacnPmDFcGTLA==*

**C# functions**

```
static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
{
    string cipherText;
    var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged()
    {
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key),
        Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
        BlockSize = 128,
    };
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(rijndael.Key, rijndael.IV);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            //cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}

private static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string key)
{
    string plainText;
    byte[] cipherArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged()
    {
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key),
        Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
        BlockSize = 128
    };
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(rijndael.Key, rijndael.IV);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherArray))
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
            {
                plainText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return plainText;
}
```

**PHP functions**

```
function string_encrypt($string, $key) {
    $crypted_text = mcrypt_encrypt(
                            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
                            $key, 
                            $string, 
                            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                        );
    return base64_encode($crypted_text);
}

function string_decrypt($encrypted_string, $key) {
    return mcrypt_decrypt(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
                    $key, 
                    base64_decode($encrypted_string), 
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    );
}
```

I am not so good in C# and I know the PHP function is working fine. So, there must be something done on C# functions. May be the string to be encrypted should converted to Latin chars.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer you have been given hsuk? It seems rather extensive...

Comment: Actually I don't want to change my PHP function ...

Comment: What about the second block of code written by StigM? That looks like C# to me. He first showed you the correct way, and then the way to make C# comply with the braindead PHP mcrypt_decrypt functionality.

Comment: Also note that you should explicitly define the [tag:character-encoding] to be used within both PHP and C#. Also note that keys and passwords are not the same, and that ECB mode is not secure for encrypting text (or for most data, really).

Answer (score 8):

C# does Rijndael padding by default and uses PKCS7.

This means you have to pad your PHP side as per PKCS7, code below should work:

```
function string_encrypt($string, $key) {

  $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  $padding = $block - (strlen($string) % $block);
  $string .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

    $crypted_text = mcrypt_encrypt(
                            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
                            $key, 
                            $string, 
                            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                        );
    return base64_encode($crypted_text);
}
```

For further information, see the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329260/cross-platform-php-to-c-sharp-net-encryption-decryption-with-rijndael)

I should add also, that if you want to change the C# side and not use padding, make the below modification **instead** and leave the PHP side alone:

```
static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
{
  string cipherText;
  var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged()
  {
    Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key),
    Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
    BlockSize = 128,
    Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
  };
  ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(rijndael.Key, null);

  using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
      using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
      {
        streamWriter.Write(plainText);
        streamWriter.Flush();
      }
      //cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray())));
      cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
      //cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    }
  }
  return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if the PaddingMode.Zeros was more prominent in this answer. Thanks!