# Decrypt String Created in C# (cipher) with PHP?

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I am using the following class to encript a string.
Now I need to decode it in PHP but I am having a hard time trying to achieve it. But firstly, do you know if that is even possible?

Also Can I use the same secret key in php?
Any ideas or any help will be appreciated

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace HySoftLocalApiNetCore
{
    class Cipher
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">String to be encrypted</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password</param>
        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string password)
        {
            if (plainText == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (password == null)
            {
                password = String.Empty;
            }

            // Get the bytes of the string
            var bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

            // Hash the password with SHA256
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            var bytesEncrypted = Cipher.Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="encryptedText">String to be decrypted</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password used during encryption</param>
        /// <exception cref="FormatException"></exception>
        public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string password)
        {
            if (encryptedText == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (password == null)
            {
                password = String.Empty;
            }

            // Get the bytes of the string
            var bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            var bytesDecrypted = Cipher.Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, passwordBytes);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
        }

        private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            var saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);

                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }

                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytes;
        }

        private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            var saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);

                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }

                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return decryptedBytes;
        }

    }
}
```

To use I simply pass the string and the password, also to decrypt, it is very easy to use it.

Comment: If you can decrypt the password you are not securely storing your passwords.

Comment: @user3783243 I think you need to examine the example more carefully.

Comment: The existing code you have is insecure.  It uses the key as an IV (yuck).  Fix this first.  Additionally, show your attempt at converting the code to PHP, we don't write code for you.  Why do you want to do this and why can't you use HTTPS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rijndael 256 Encrypt/decrypt between c# and php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431950/rijndael-256-encrypt-decrypt-between-c-sharp-and-php)

Comment: You should be able to decrypt your data with [`openssl_decrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) using `AES-256-CBC` and [`hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) using `SHA256`. I may be able to help more if you show us your PHP code.